# getOrElse for an Option(null) does not return a None type or the default value when null in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, optional-parameters

I am trying to initialize a list in Spark using scala, from a column of data. The value in some of the rows can be empty, and in some rows it's filled. So I am making my list of type `Option[String]`. But, when I access the elements in it, scala returns a `Some` for each element, including empty values, even if they have been initialized using `Option(null)`. This means that when I try to get the value as `getOrElse("0")`, it prints `Some()` if the value should have been "0". In code, this is what I am doing:

```
val columnsToRead: List[String] = List("__id", "device");

val selectedColumnsDataset: Array[List[(String, Option[String])]] =
    dataset.map(s => {columnsToUseForCorrelation
    .map(t => (t, Option(s.getAs[String](t))))
}).collect();
```

I confirmed that the expression `s.getAs[String](t)` returns a null if `t` isn't in the row, by writing this alternate map

```
val selectedColumnsDataset2: Array[List[(String, Option[String])]] = 
    dataset.map(s => {columnsToUseForCorrelation
    .map(t => (t, s.getAs[String](t)))
    .map(t => (t._1, if (t._2 == null) Option(null) else Option(t._2)))
}).collect();
```

Both of these expressions return the same output, so I think I am doing it correctly. The problem I  face is when I try to print out the values in here. One thing I have to do first is to convert the `list` to a `wrappedarray`, which I don't understand where the implicit conversion happens, but it throws an exception if I do a map on the lists. This is my code for printing out those values:

```
    val selectedColumnsParsed = selectedColumnsDataset.asInstanceOf[Array[mutable.WrappedArray.ofRef[(String, Option[String])]]];

    selectedColumnsParsed.foreach(s => {
        s.foreach(t => {
        println(t._2.getOrElse("0"), t._2)
        })
    })
```

The output I get from these is

```
(440,Some(440))
(157,Some(157))
(441,Some(441))
(,Some())
(,Some())
(443,Some(443))
(,Some())
```

The empty values show that they are empty, so they should have been casted automatically to a `None` type, but instead they are a `Some` type, and I don't understand how they aren't `Some(null)` as they should be. The strings look like they are empty of length 0, but calling `isEmpty` in the println statements throws a null pointer exception, so that means that the `getOrElse` should return the default value `0`, but it does not do that. What is the proper way to initialize the `Option` type so that a `null` is matched to a `None` type?

Comment: It looks good to me. `Option(null)` should return `None`. Have you tried `s.getAs[Option[String]](t)`?

Answer (score 1):

> The value in some of the rows can be empty

Empty (blank) is not the same as `null`:

```
"".isEmpty
// Boolean = true

"" == null
// Boolean = false
```

so consequently `Option` of empty string, is not `None`:

```
Option("")
// Option[String] = Some()
```

> One thing I have to do first is to convert the list to a wrappedarray, which I don't understand where the implicit conversion happens,

This happens because data stored in `Dataset` is encoded. We don't depend on specific implementation, but on interfaces. Here you should really use `Seq`.

To keep things clean, I would go with something simpler:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val columnsToRead: List[String] = List("__id", "device");
val dataset = Seq( 
  ("foo", null, 0),  // Here we expect None
  ("bar", "", -1),   // Here we expect Some("")
  ("xyz", "zyx", 1)
).toDF("__id", "device", "some_val")

dataset
  .select(array(columnsToRead map col: _*))
  .as[Seq[Option[String]]]
  .map(columnsToRead.zip(_))
  .collect.foreach(println)
// List((__id,Some(foo)), (device,None))
// List((__id,Some(bar)), (device,Some()))
// List((__id,Some(xyz)), (device,Some(zyx)))
```

or

```
dataset
  .select(columnsToRead map(c => struct(lit(c), col(c))): _*)
  .as[((String, Option[String]), (String, Option[String]))]
  .collect.foreach(println)

// ((__id,Some(foo)),(device,None))
// ((__id,Some(bar)),(device,Some()))
// ((__id,Some(xyz)),(device,Some(zyx)))
```

If you want blank strings to be `None` you'll have to handle this explicitly.